# How to simplify stopping movement of image when within threshold of target

Tags: c#, comparison, move, target

I've already tried to explain what I'm trying to do to others, and failed horribly. Therefore, if you will excuse me, I'll just show you the code and attempt to explain a little.

```
        if (MovePetMoving)
        {
            if (MovePetSlope[0] > 0)
            {
                if (MovePetSlope[1] > 0 && Convert.ToDouble(pictureBoxPet.Location.X) + MovePetSlope[0] <= MovePetTarget[0] && Convert.ToDouble(pictureBoxPet.Location.Y) + MovePetSlope[1] <= MovePetTarget[1])
                {
                    MovePetWorker(pictureBoxPet, pictureBoxPet.Location.X + MovePetSlope[0], pictureBoxPet.Location.Y + MovePetSlope[1]);
                    //MsgBox("MovePetSlope[0] > 0 and MovePetSlope[1] > 0", "");
                }
                else if (MovePetSlope[1] < 0 && Convert.ToDouble(pictureBoxPet.Location.X) + MovePetSlope[0] <= MovePetTarget[0] && Convert.ToDouble(pictureBoxPet.Location.Y) + MovePetSlope[1] >= MovePetTarget[1])
                {
                    MovePetWorker(pictureBoxPet, pictureBoxPet.Location.X + MovePetSlope[0], pictureBoxPet.Location.Y + MovePetSlope[1]);
                    //MsgBox("MovePetSlope[0] > 0 and MovePetSlope[1] < 0", "");
                }
                else
                {
                    MovePetMoving = false;
                    //MsgBox("Error", "");
                }
            }
            else if (MovePetSlope[0] < 0)
            {
                if (MovePetSlope[1] > 0 && Convert.ToDouble(pictureBoxPet.Location.X) + MovePetSlope[0] >= MovePetTarget[0] && Convert.ToDouble(pictureBoxPet.Location.Y) + MovePetSlope[1] <= MovePetTarget[1])
                {
                    MovePetWorker(pictureBoxPet, pictureBoxPet.Location.X + MovePetSlope[0], pictureBoxPet.Location.Y + MovePetSlope[1]);
                    //MsgBox("MovePetSlope[0] < 0 and MovePetSlope[1] > 0", "");
                }
                else if (MovePetSlope[1] < 0 && Convert.ToDouble(pictureBoxPet.Location.X) + MovePetSlope[0] >= MovePetTarget[0] && Convert.ToDouble(pictureBoxPet.Location.Y) + MovePetSlope[1] >= MovePetTarget[1])
                {
                    MovePetWorker(pictureBoxPet, pictureBoxPet.Location.X + MovePetSlope[0], pictureBoxPet.Location.Y + MovePetSlope[1]);
                    //MsgBox("MovePetSlope[0] < 0 and MovePetSlope[1] < 0" + Convert.ToString(pictureBoxPet.Location.X) + MovePetSlope[0] + MovePetTarget[0], "");
                }
                else
                {
                    MovePetMoving = false;
                    //MsgBox("Error", "");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

There it is. If you're wondering about all the references to "pet" are, I'm making a tamogotchi (or however you spell it) like game for my little little sister.

The problem I have is that the value of MovePetSlope[1] or [0] can either be positive or negative. I've come up with some comparisons that work for positive values, but none for negative values. I believe that in it's current state, it doesn't work at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?  Whatever it is, I doubt more ifs and elses are the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to get the image to stop moving once it reaches the target destination. A modification to the initial post; the current code actually works, I was thinking about another one which I had tried.

Comment: One word: refactor. The code the way you have is very difficult to work with, look at and therefore error prone. As a first step i would assign and convert the values you're comparing  before your initial if block. You'll see how much easier to read it will be and i have no doubt that you'll find a silly bug.

Comment: E.g. change Convert.ToDouble(pictureBoxPet.Location.X) to 
double petLocX = Convert.ToDouble(pictureBoxPet.Location.X);
if (...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Math.Abs to simplify your comparisons.
In general the pet should keep moving until `Math.Abs(pictureBoxPet.Location.X-MovePetTarget[0]) < Math.Abs(MovePetSlope[0])` and analogously for Y and 1.  You should end up with *much* simpler code.

If your pet is moving directly towards the target, this should do the trick:

```
if (MovePetMoving)
{
    if (Math.Abs(pictureBoxPet.Location.X-MovePetTarget[0]) < Math.Abs(MovePetSlope[0]))
        MovePetMoving = false;
    else
        MovePetWorker(pictureBoxPet, pictureBoxPet.Location.X + MovePetSlope[0], pictureBoxPet.Location.Y + MovePetSlope[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mick, I'll try that out right now. I'll look up "refractor" also. EDIT: haha, refractor is to simplify. :)

Comment: It just means to rewrite the same code in a way that is easier to look at and maintain, or is just more elegant or useful.

Comment: It worked! I just had to change the less than sign to a greater than sign, but that's probably because I wasn't clear in explaining what the values would typically be.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A different strategy :

1. define a variable of type Rectangle that holds the targets bounds in screen co-ordinates : increase the bounds as necessary according to some threshold variable you define.
2. define MouseUp and MouseDown event handlers for the PictureBox
3. define a boolean variable (in form scope) that is set to true when the mouse goes down (in the MouseDown Event Handler) on the PictureBox, and false in the MouseUp handler for the PictureBox.
4. define a MouseMove Event handler for the PictureBox in which :

   a. if the boolean variable is true (mouse is down)

   1. use the Rectangle.IntersectsWith method to see if the current bounds of the PictureBox overlaps the target bounds rectangle. [MSDN Rectangle.IntersectsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith(VS.85).aspx?queryresult=true) : if it does you know you can stop.

imho, using this stragety you can write greatly simplified code.

Comment: Thanks BillW, I will look into this also. Though I'm not using a mouse, "strategy tips" #s 1 and 4b will work for me.

Thanks!